# Why can't I use external JDBC Maven project in servlet web app as dependency?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jdbc

I use an external JDBC Maven project in servlet web app as dependency. It works independently, but when I use service classes in servlet class, I get a notification like this:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niLdu.jpg)

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you can connect to that MySql host from the host on which the webapp is running in normal circumstances with the same credentials, the chance is that you don't have the driver jar in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: i got it done now, it is due to class.forName required when use it inner together